# unable to attach acr with aks

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-aks

I have use following command to attach AKS with ACR

```
az aks create -n myAKSCluster -g myResourceGroup --attach-acr $MYACR
```

But the error still persist while fetching image. Then I did a little more investigation to find what all service principal ids are attached using following

```
az aks list
```

and I get [] empty array list. Any clue what I might be missing?

az role assignment list --assignee  --scope

Comment: What is the value of `$MYACR` ? If the registry is not in the same subscription as the cluster you will have to pass the full resource id (not just the name)

Comment: name of container registry. aks and acr both are in same subscription

Comment: What's about the issue now? Do you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can first set the subscription using the following command and then can try with further ones to map ACR to AKS

```
 az account set --subscription
```

there are two ways to get this sorted

Map the ACR to AKS

```
CLIENT_ID=$(az aks show --resource-group $AKS_RESOURCE_GROUP --name 
$AKS_CLUSTER_NAME --subscription $SUBSCRIPTION_ID --query "servicePrincipalProfile.clientId" --output tsv)

ACR_ID=$(az acr show --name $ACR_NAME --resource-group $ACR_RESOURCE_GROUP --subscription $SUBSCRIPTION_ID --query "id" --output tsv)

az role assignment create --assignee $CLIENT_ID --role Reader --scope $ACR_ID
```

Comment: Cannot find user or service principal in graph database for "xxx",If the assignee is an appId, make sure the corresponding service principal is created with 'az ad sp create --id xxx'.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if your cluster is already attached to ACR.

```
az aks check-acr --name myAKSCluster --resource-group myResourceGroup --acr myAcr.azurecr.io
```

If already attached you will get a message like "Your cluster can now pull images from ACR". If you get an error code like 403 you can attach ACR to existing cluster with this command

```
az aks update -n myAKSCluster -g myResourceGroup --attach-acr myAcr
```

You can also attach ACR to AKS from different subscription.

```
az aks update -g myResourceGroup -n myAKSCluster --attach-acr "/subscriptions/{subcription-id}/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/myAcr"
```